# Partial derivative not parallel to $x$ or $y$ axis

Tags: geometry

In [attached](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/partial/partial.html) example I want to find slope along $x=y$ direction. I know how to find partial derivatives when we are parallel to $x$ axis (keep $y$ constant and take partial derivative with respect to $x$) or $y$ axis, but I don't know how to get find slope/derivative when we are not parallel to any of those axis.

My thinking is that to find the slope along $x=y$ direction, in curves' equation we can replace $x$ with $y$ and then take a derivative with respect to $x$. Is that correct?

Comment: You just dot-product the partial with the direction of the vector along which you want to find the derivative; in this case, a direction vector would be $(1,1,z_0)$ for some value $z_0$

Comment: You need to be careful. If you want to find the slope along the $x=y$ direction at a point on the $x=y$ line, then you can do what you wrote above. However, if you are not on the $x=y$ line, then you cannot do the above.

Comment: @ copper.hat: Do you mean the general idea is wrong, or the specific choice of $(1,1,z_0)$?

Comment: @DBFdalwayse would it be possible to show the solution with the main steps? I can get partial derivative with respect to x and y, but then I am not sure what to do...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming we're talking about a situation where we have some function $z = f(x,y)$, which describes a surface as a function of $x$ and $y$. Let's focus our attention on some specific point $\mathbf{P} = (a,b)$. If you know $f_x = \partial f / \partial x$ and $f_y = \partial f / \partial y$ at $\mathbf{P}$, then you can construct two vectors $\mathbf{v}_x = (1,0, f_x)$ and $\mathbf{v}_y = (0, 1, f_y)$ that lie in the tangent plane $\pi_1$ at $\mathbf{P}$. The normal vector of $\pi_1$ is $\mathbf{n}_1 = \mathbf{v}_x \times \mathbf{v}_y = (-f_x, -f_y, 1)$.

The slopes/derivatives that you're interested in can be described by tangent lines lying in the tangent plane $\pi_1$ that are obtaining by slicing $\pi_1$ with vertical planes having various orientations. For example, slicing with the vertical plane $x=a$ will give us back the partial derivative $f_x$.

Specifically, suppose we are given a vector $\mathbf{u} = (u_x, u_y,0)$ lying in the $xy$-plane, and we want to know about the slope of the surface in the direction of $\mathbf{u}$. We can construct a vertical plane $\pi_2$ containing the point $\mathbf{P}$ and the vector $\mathbf{u}$ and use it to "slice" the surface. But, we don't really need to slice the surface itself, we only need to slice its tangent plane $\pi_1$. This will give us a tangent line that defines the "slope" of the surface in the direction $\mathbf{u}$. The normal of $\pi_2$ is in the direction $\mathbf{n}_2 = (-d_y, d_x, 0)$, so the direction of the tangent line is $\mathbf{n}_1 \times \mathbf{n}_2 = (u_x, u_y, u_x f_x + u_y f_y)$.

In your case $\mathbf{u} = (1,1,0)$, and the vertical plane $\pi_2$ is the plane $x=y$. The intersection of the surface tangent plane and the plane $\pi_2$ is a line in the direction of $(u_x, u_y, u_x f_x + u_y f_y) = (1,1,f_x + f_y)$.

If we take $\mathbf{u} = (1,0,0)$, then the tangent line direction is $(1,0,f_x)$, which is exactly what we would expect, because the tangent line in this direction corresponds to the partial derivative $f_x$.

I think that all of this is consistent with the answer given by copper.hat. My answer is just more geometric (and more long-winded) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally to find the slope in a particular direction, consider the function $\phi(t) = f(x+t d$). Then $\phi'(0) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} d$.

In terms of coordinates, $\phi'(0) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} d_i$.

In your example, $d = (1,1)^T$.

Depending on your application, you may want to scale $d$ to have unit norm.

Comment: a bit confused here. The function that you have mentioned above is of a single variable, I have 2 variable x and y in my function. I can partial derivatives. Then what are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

In general $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\textbf{l}}=\nabla u\cdot\textbf{l}$$ is the expression for derivative along $\textbf{l}$, if $\|\textbf l\|=1$